# Laravel Apis not working in postman in localhost

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-artisan, artisan-serve

I have developed apis into php laravel, and developing on the local server and running them using

```
php artisan serve
```

these apis are working in the website but whenever i try to access them in postman it returns **419** response code with a message
**Page Expired**.

After googling the debugging the requests from websites i found out headers to pass with the request.
So i passed

```
_token 
X-CSRF-Token
```

and also selected **Bearer Token** in Authorization tab. Even after adding these parameters in headers it did not work out. I tried adding them with body but it did not work there as well.

The code snippets are

```
Route::post('/register_user', 'MyUserController@storeApi');
```

**MyUserController**

```
 public function storeApi(Request $request)
 {   
     
        $userModel = new User;
        $userModel->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
        $userModel->last_name = $request->input('last_name');
        $userModel->save();
    
        $userId = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

        $response['status'] = 'ok';
        $response['response'] = $userId ;
        return response()->json($response);
            
 }
```

[image]

So my question is, how to make it work in local server using postman.

Comment: You should share the code too so that we may help you.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi I have added the image and code too. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are adding the headers with values or just the headers?

Comment: @Borjante ofcourse headers with the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `api.php` file
and call the route with api prefix like this :

in **api.php** :

```
Route::get('/test','Controller@function');
```

in **postman** :

```
GET: localhost:8000/api/test
```